# getting visitors city from their IP not working geoplugin

Tags: php, geoip

```
a:18:{s:17:"geoplugin_request";s:13:"175.101.68.70";s:16:"geoplugin_status";i:206;s:16:"geoplugin_credit";s:145:"Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from <a href=\'http://www.maxmind.com\'>http://www.maxmind.com</a>.";s:14:"geoplugin_city";s:0:"";s:16:"geoplugin_region";s:0:"";s:18:"geoplugin_areaCode";s:1:"0";s:17:"geoplugin_dmaCode";s:1:"0";s:21:"geoplugin_countryCode";s:2:"IN";s:21:"geoplugin_countryName";s:5:"India";s:23:"geoplugin_continentCode";s:2:"AS";s:18:"geoplugin_latitude";s:2:"20";s:19:"geoplugin_longitude";s:2:"77";s:20:"geoplugin_regionCode";s:0:"";s:20:"geoplugin_regionName";N;s:22:"geoplugin_currencyCode";s:3:"INR";s:24:"geoplugin_currencySymbol";s:7:"&#8360;";s:29:"geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8";s:3:"₨";s:27:"geoplugin_currencyConverter";s:5:"61.62";}
```

geoplugin_city is not getting from last two days , before two days back it worked fine, i don't know what happened , i didn't change the code also, is there any geoplugin server error.

Comment: Maybe the plugin is unable to determine the city? Getting location data from IP addresses is not guaranteed to work 100% all the time.

Comment: What service are you getting this response from?

Comment: @duskwuff Probably the [geoip plugin](http://php.net/geoip).

Answer (score 0):

The geoplugin_status codes translates to this

**200** - Full data returned

**206** - Only country data

**404** - No data found for the IP at all

In your case, the server seems to have only the country data.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/geoplugin/geoplugin_status$20/geoplugin/qcrr8WIhh4Q/Lbus9APA26MJ